# Android get height of a wrap content view inflated as 0dp

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, layoutparams

I'm currently working on animation that will grow up the view if the user clicks it. Basically, its a card that, when clicked, it will reveal the bottom content. For that, I'm extending Animation like this:

```
Val collapseAnimation = object : Animation() {
            override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                val interpolatedInverted = 1 - interpolatedTime

                val headerLp = headerImage.layoutParams
                headerLp.width = ...
                headerImage.layoutParams = headerLp
            }
        }
```

The problem is that i need to get the height of a view (wrap_content) that is defined in XML as 0dp. Basically, I want to grow up a view from 0dp to wrap_content and for that i need to know what is the wrap_content size.

How can I accomplish that in the most efficient way, without hard coding the view size?

Comment: try using a ViewTreeObserver to get the size at runtime. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Comment: the view is initially inflated as 0dp, so it won't work with only this solution i think

Comment: Once the view is laid out, calling `getWidth` on the view will return the actual width.  So just don't call this in `onCreateView`.  You can use the `ViewTreeObserver` as suggested to make sure the view has been laid out.

Comment: if the view is defined in xml with height 0dp, how can viewtree observable return an actual height? the view is defined as having 0dp in height, i want to know its size with wrap_content without actually setting it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to measure a view with different layout params and get its height, we can do the following:

```
contentContainer.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
val contentContainerFinalHeight = contentContainer.measuredHeight
```